# Problem connecting to postgres ontainer with strapi backend. Npm using windows username to authenticate

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, npm, strapi

I am new to strapi and deploying locally on windows to learn. I can deploy using default (SQLite) easily but run into problems using a custom installation with postgres:

Env:

- **Strapi Version**: 4.9.1
- **Operating System**: Win 10
- **Database**: postgres:14.7-alpine3.17 (docker container)
- **Node Version**: 18.12.2
- **NPM Version**: 9.6.2

---

I have problems starting a new strapi backend using the `npm run develop` command.

I am starting a postgres in a container like so:

```
docker run --name=strapi -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_DB=planrec -e POSTGRES_USER=strapi -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=strapi -d postgres:14.7-alpine3.17
```

The container is already running when i run `npm run develop`. This is the output from npm:

```
> planrec@0.1.0 develop
> strapi develop

Starting the compilation for TypeScript files in C:\code\planrec
Building your admin UI with development configuration...
Admin UI built successfully
[2023-04-13 08:16:12.496] debug: ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2023-04-13 08:16:12.499] error: password authentication failed for user "benxa"
error: password authentication failed for user "benxa"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\code\planrec\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (C:\code\planrec\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (C:\code\planrec\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\code\planrec\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
```

benxa is my windows username on this machine. I know that postgres will default to windows username for authentication. What I find odd is that it appears to be ignoring all the values in .env:

```
HOST=0.0.0.0
PORT=1337
APP_KEYS=NJEKqyvxhRmDhRnoMlARrQ==,jc4fpMWmorT3rpjSRsdxsg==,f5SWsMiILKJzS8C56YOfmw==,YGdCXBZqT2ndRM7ZSrY4DQ==
API_TOKEN_SALT=OFRYyQTxJfu6oJHmw9s6iQ==
ADMIN_JWT_SECRET=ncZ4NxWv9RwtvVaI6doxAg==
TRANSFER_TOKEN_SALT=QWetO67oSvn7dEh6e9KPnA==
# Database
DATABASE_CLIENT=postgres
DATABASE_HOST=127.0.01
DATABASE_PORT=5432
DATABASE_NAME=planrec
DATABASE_USERNAME=strapi
DATABASE_PASSWORD=strapi
DATABASE_SSL=false
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://strapi:strapi@localhost:5432/planrec?sslmode=disable"
```

I added `DATABASE_URL` on my last try to connect.

Any thoughts appreciated.